# How to format the result from using Delt function in quantmod package in r

Tags: r, format, quantmod

I have got a great result from using Delt function from quantmod package in R.
However, the format of the result it not quiet how I want. It is something like -0.046984753. I want the number something as -4.7% if it makes sense!

help experts!!

Thank you!

Comment: post your code that generated your result please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `scales`

```
 library('scales')
 result=-0.046984753
 percent(result)
 [1] "-4.7%"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Hello! I have found a problem with the code. It works fine. However, it adds '%' sign to 'NA' value also. so it shows as 'NA%'. Any idea to fix it?

Comment: `percent`:a function with single parameter x, `a numeric vector`, that returns a character vector

Comment: How you can input `NA` and using `percent` without the error .

Comment: OK glad it help